Does the idiom 'Vinaash kale viprit buddhi' comes from any actual hindu scriptures?
Is it some kind of a shloka mentioned in some scripture? If yes, then which one?


na nirmitō na chaiva na dṛṣṭapūrvō
na śrūyatē hēmamayaḥ kuraṅgaḥ ।
tathā'pi tṛṣṇā raghunandanasya
vināśakālē viparītabuddhiḥ ॥
No one did ever see or hear about any golden deer nor it was ever created, still behold the craving of raghunandana (rāma)! Indeed one’s wisdom fails at the onset of bad fate. [chāṇakya expresses wonder that how Lord rāma could be lured by that golden deer – for which sītā forced him to go and get it for herself, when no such doe was ever created, seen or heard about by anyone. Regrettably, he says that indeed the onset of evil days is heralded by the failure of one’s common sense or wisdom. This last phrase vināśakālē viparītabuddhiḥ is one of the most quoted expressions even in the modern times.] Chanakya Niti 16.5  online credits

